# SetFieldValue is not working in Suitelet Script

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I've just built suitelet script which is using saved search.

Here is my code. 
Here search_id is saved search id.

```
var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('item', search_id, null, null);

if(searchresults){

    for ( var i = 0; searchresults != null && i < searchresults.length; i++ ) {
        var record = nlapiLoadRecord(searchresults[i].getRecordType(),
                        searchresults[i].getId() );
        record.setFieldValue('baserecordtype','inventoryitem');
        nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
    }
}
```

I hoped this could be working but didn't work properly.

Please let me know what mistakes I made. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field you might be setting could be a read-only field.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, You can't change the base type of an item, even via script. The exception is to go from a non inventory to an inventory item. Not sure if this can be done via script. A case to Netsuite support will confirm.